# Is the Gibbs free energy not/less important for canonical ensembles? If so, why?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

From canonical ensembles, we find that the Helmholtz free energy $F=U-TS$ is related to the canonical partition function as $$F=U-TS=-k_BT\ln Z$$ where $Z$ is the canonical partition function. Therefore, the Gibbs free energy $G$ is given by $$G=F+PV=-k_BT\ln Z+\frac{1}{\beta}V\frac{\partial}{\partial V}(\ln Z)$$ where the expression of pressure $P$ has been used. But textbooks typically mention Helmholtz free energy $F$ but not Gibbs free energy in the context of canonical ensembles. Is Gibbs free energy not as useful as Helmholtz free energy for canonical ensembles? If so, why?

Comment: I think the statement of your question answers this. See how a nice relation comes for the Helmholtz free energy under the assumptions of the canonical ensemble, but not for the Gibbs free energy? Also, the Helmoltz free energy is more useful in systems at constant temperature and volume, which is usually assumed in this case.

Comment: @AaronStevens But would you say G is less relevant than F for canonical ensembles?

Comment: I would say relevance completely depends on what you are actually trying to calculate or understand. What type of relevance are you trying to discuss here?

Comment: @AaronStevens So you argue that since the equilibrium of systems with constant T and constant V are determined by the minimum of F, it more relevant compared to G?

Comment: Can we have canonical ensembles for which the P and T are constants, and therefore G is more relevant? I'm interested in studying the equilibrium properties of the system.

Comment: I would say so. Just like how in the microcanonical ensemble we focus more on entropy maximization. We can say for sure "This system we are looking at under these constraints will move to minimize the Helmholtz free energy". Thus we have a well defined condition for equilibrium.

Answer (score 5):

$G$ and $F$ are the thermodynamic potentials of different ensembles, the one for $G$ has, as far as I know, no commonly accepted name. The one for $F$ is the canonical ensemble.

The bath in the ensemble corresponding to $G$ can exchange volume and energy with the system and is characterized by two intense parameters the system gets into equilibrium with: temperature and pressure.

For a system characterized by the common parameters $S$, $N$, $V$ there are 8 ensembles depending on which are considered fixed or exchanged with the bath. The bath is then characterized by the corresponding intensive parameters ($T$, $\mu$ and $p$).

The thermodynamic potentials that are extremal in the equilibrium of those ensembles are related by Legendre transformations that change the variables from a quantity to the derivative of the function with respect to that quantity (yes, the same Legendre transformation as in Hamiltonian mechanics). The potential of the microcanoical ensemble is the energy $E(S, V, N)$ expressed in terms *of the natural variables*. From there we get to the Free energy by a Legendre transform $F = E - TS$, where $T = \partial_S E$ and $S$ must be eliminated by calculating and substituting $S(T)$ to express $F$ in terms of its so called *natural variables*.

As a general thermodynamic result the potential corresponding to the ensemble with the bath parameters $(T, \mu, p)$ is zero. This gives the Gibbs-Duhem relation:
$$ S \, dT - V\,dp + N\,d\mu = 0 $$

If we introduce other quantities describing the overall system (e.g. magnetization) there are even more ensembles and we again can change between extensive and intensive parameters by Legendre transformation.